# ¿Qué hacen exactamente estos servicios de Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Soy nuevo y quisiera saber que hacen exactamente estos servicios de oracle:
OracleJobSchedulerXE,
OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener,
OracleServiceXE

Answer (score 1):

El job scheduler mantiene todas las tareas programadas del motor.
El listener es el encargado de abrir el socket en el puerto y conectar tu conexión entrante con una base de datos
El service es el proceso principal, que corresponde a la instancia de base de datos.

Revisaste la documentación oficial? Deberías.